# How to select data from the table with the following criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, vb.net-2010

How can i select fields from a table with the date in the date column.?

My select condition is dates greater than or equal to todays date. 
Am using sql server 2008 as backend and vb.net as the frontend. As i am a beginner somebody please help.

Lets say "datefrom" is the column with date and "tbl_activity" is the table name..

I tried this code.

```
cmd.commandText="SELECT activity FROM tbl_activity WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), 'datefrom')>=0"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: [***What have you tried?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Your question is about basic use of SQL... specifically the `where` clause. Please edit your question and include the attempts you've made so far

Comment: EDIT and Be clear on your question i see so many '?'.add your tries so far.

Comment: i got what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT activity FROM tbl_activity WHERE datefrom>= Convert(Date, GetDate(), 101)
```

Note:datefrom is the DATETIME column